# Using Freemarker template tags in Angular 2

Tags: angular, macos, angular2-template, freemarker

I am trying to write an FTL page and use Freemarker template tags to include basic things straight from the server. In my Main.ftl, I have the following

`<p> Account logged in is ${model.Account.getAccountId()}</P.`

However, when I try to build in Angular, the Angular engines complains that it doesn't know what model is, despite the fact that I'm trying to call this from Freemarker instead of the Angular engine. Is there a way I can tell Angular to ignore things from Freemarker? Thanks.
--------------Edit--------------------
It seems the error is coming from the Html Webpack Plugin This is the error I'm getting in the file when it tries to process it.

`Html Webpack Plugin:

```
  ReferenceError: model is not defined
  - Main.ftl:75 
    /usr/local/project/Angular/src/Main.ftl:75:10
```

- Main.ftl:78 ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/Main.ftl.module.exports
  /usr/local/project/Angular/src/Main.ftl:78:3
- index.js:264 
  [Angular]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:264:16
- util.js:16 tryCatcher
  [Angular]/[bluebird]/js/release/util.js:16:23
- promise.js:512 Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler
  [Angular]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:512:31
- promise.js:569 Promise._settlePromise
  [Angular]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:569:18
- promise.js:606 Promise._settlePromiseCtx
  [Angular]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:606:10
- async.js:138 Async._drainQueue
  [Angular]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:138:12
- async.js:143 Async._drainQueues
  [Angular]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:143:10
- async.js:17 Immediate.Async.drainQueues
  [Angular]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:17:14

`

Another thing, I don't seem to get this error on Windows, but I do when I'm using my mac (although that could be something else, since my git repo did not seem to transfer well from Mac to Windows).

Comment: template should be evaluate in server side before reaching angular which is client side

Comment: That's what I assumed. However, when I run "ng build" it fails and spits out errors about it not finding any variables called "model."

Comment: Is it Angular who complains, or FreeMarker, or something other that participates in the build? Because as far as I know `${...}` is not special for Angular. (BTW, in FreeMarker usually you can just write `foo.accountId` instead of `foo.getAccountId()`.)

Comment: It's Angular that's complaining. When I run "ng build", it gives me the following error ERROR in Template execution failed: ReferenceError: model is not defined
ERROR in   ReferenceError: model is not defined